# Good reference for noncommutative $L^p$ spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, von-neumann-algebras

I'm looking for good references to learn about $L^p$ spaces associated with von Neumann algebras. I already know about Uffe Haagerup's paper "$L^p$-[spaces associated with an arbitrary von Neumann algebra](https://dmitripavlov.org/scans/haagerup.pdf)"; but I'm looking for further references. Can you please recommend me some other documents?

Comment: Do you know the survey "Non-commutative $L^p$ spaces" by Pisier and Xu in the Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces? If you are specifically interested in Haagerup's construction, the classical reference is Terp's notes "$L^p$-spaces associated with von neumann algebras". If not in your library, these two papers can be easily found on google.

Comment: What aspects of noncommutative L_p-spaces are of interest to you?  If you are interested in the underlying algebraic structure of L_p-spaces and its connections to the Tomita-Takesaki modular theory, the best references are Yamagami's papers “Algebraic aspects in modular theory” and “Modular theory for bimodules”.