# Books on von Neumann algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, fourier-analysis, von-neumann-algebras, textbook-recommendation

I am interested in non-commutative $L^p$ spaces. I have a very basic background on von Neumann algebras.  But all the papers appearing now a days really requires very deep knowledge of von Neumann algebras. Also the theory of von Neumann algebras is very vast. So can anyone tell me some of the books or lecture notes on von Neumann algebras and the specific topics of von Neumann algebras which will be sufficient for me to start studying recent papers in this field? My background in Real Variable Theory is good. So I am mostly interested in Littlewood-Paley theory/ Calderon-Zygmund theory on non-commutative $L^p$ spaces.

Comment: Why don't you ask your adviser?? He is the best person to know what will be useful for you.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236853/good-reference-for-noncommutative-lp-spaces?rq=1 for books on non-commutative $L^p$ spaces in particular.

Comment: Takesaki, volumes 1 and 2.

Comment: And honestly, I don't see why this question was put on hold.

Comment: Yamagami's paper "Algebraic aspects in modular theory" does a really good job explaining noncommutative L^p-spaces and related topics like Tomita-Takesaki theory, highly recommended.

Comment: Vaughan Jones von Neumann algebras lite https://math.vanderbilt.edu/jonesvf/VONNEUMANNALGEBRAS2015/VonNeumann2015.pdf

Comment: There is a very nice book by Popa and Anantharaman-Delaroche on finite von Neumann algebras [available here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/Books/IIun-v13.pdf). There are also interesting notes by Xu on $L^{p}$-spaces [available here](http://www.nim.nankai.edu.cn/activites/conferences/hy200707/summer-school/xu-long.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Bischoff and Wasilewski!! The lecture notes by Xu really looks very self-contained.